# ERROR 403 in Django even after configuring the django-cors-headers package

Tags: django

Is the django-cors-headers exclusive to the DRF? If not, why am I getting an error 403 if I am not using DRF in my project?

I already configured the django-cors-header package.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'api',
'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',


'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',


'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8000', 
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about it but I think you should place CorsMiddleWare above CsrfViewMiddleware.

Comment: I already did that configuration, but unfortunately, it still wasn't the solution.

Comment: To better assist you, could you please share the relevant sections of your views and HTML templates?Understanding how your views handle requests and how your templates render content can help me pinpoint the cause of the 403 Forbidden error you're encountering.